# Dialogue boxes steal focus form current application

Tags: .desktop, usability

I was jut typing an email when an Ubuntu error message popped up. Since I was pressing enter or space while typing I either OKed or Cancelled something. I think it's really bad to steal the focus of the current application.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?